# What happens to the swap usage in live cd for Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: boot, swap

**If I have Ubuntu 17.04 installed**, now that it does not require a separate **swap**, but instead relies on a swap file,
What happens to the swap usage of live sessions? Do they use the swap file of the current installation, or they cannot use any swap, in the absence of a separate parition?

Comment: I would theirs is setup to be used for just that moment... Not sure though!

Comment: Just test it with the `swapon`-command. Boot to your install and run `swapon`, this will tell you which swap-areas are used. Then boot to Ubuntu live and run the same command, you will see if your swap-file in your install is used or not. But don't use hibernation to test it out.